# redirecting on flask from a 'POST' route to a 'GET' route

Tags: python, flask

I want to redirect to another url( of a route whose method by default is 'GET') from a route whose method has been set to 'POST' if some condition is met. The 'GET' route gets called when I check from the terminal, but the redirection doesn't happen from the browser. Am doing this in flask using 'url_for'. Any help?

I've tried using the `_method` parameter in the `url_for` ,i.e, `return redirect(url_for('second', _method='GET')`

Here's some code:

```py
@app.route('/first', methods=['POST'])
def first():
    some_data = request.get_json(force=True)
    if some_data is None:
       return redirect(url_for('second', _method='GET'))
     session['data_to_use'] = some_data
    return jsonify(some_data)
```

```py
@app.route('/second')
def second():
    return render_template('second.html')
```

This is what I get on the terminal:

```
"POST /first HTTP/1.1" 302 -
 "GET /second HTTP/1.1" 200 -
```

Comment: Your question is unclear to me. What do you mean on the terminal? What do you see in the browser? Does an error gets called?

Comment: Completely with @Wimanicesir . Remember that terminal is logging you all the redirections and other stuff for you to debug and check . And if you see there is Get method called for the 'second' route then it is indeed called with the Get method.

Comment: @Wimanicesir I mean when I check the logs from the terminal. Also, no error is getting called on the browser,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure your "some_data" value is None? Redirect usually should work just with ordinary url_for usage even if you are redirecting from post to get, like this:

```
@app.route('/first', methods=['POST'])
def first():
    some_data = request.get_json(force=True)
    if some_data is None:
        return redirect(url_for('second'))
    session['data_to_use'] = some_data
    return jsonify(some_data)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just return the name of the function that renders the template

```
@app.route('/first', methods=['POST'])
def first():
    some_data = request.get_json(force=True)
    if some_data is None:
       return second()
     session['data_to_use'] = some_data
    return jsonify(some_data)
```